# How would I put an ID tag inside this anchor to hide and show through java script

Tags: html

I don't need the java script I just need to know where the id goes

```
<a href='javascript:SetDetailSpanStatus(document.forms["Main"]["showtb"],0);ToggleDisplay("spanDetails", "");ToggleDisplay("spanSummary", "");'>Show Pay Period Summary</A>
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of attributes should not matter, so you can make it a sibling of the `href` attribute either before:

```
<a id="yourID" href='javascript:SetDetailSpanStatus(document.forms["Main"]["showtb"],0);ToggleDisplay("spanDetails", "");ToggleDisplay("spanSummary", "");'>Show Pay Period Summary</A>
```

or after:

```
<a href='javascript:SetDetailSpanStatus(document.forms["Main"]["showtb"],0);ToggleDisplay("spanDetails", "");ToggleDisplay("spanSummary", "");' id="yourID">Show Pay Period Summary</A>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right here:

```
<a id="IDHERE" href='javascript:SetDetailSpanStatus(document.forms["Main"]["showtb"],0);ToggleDisplay("spanDetails", "");ToggleDisplay("spanSummary", "");'>Show Pay Period Summary</A>

        ^^^^
```